# Why is this giving me a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
String line = "";
BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
StringTokenizer x = new StringTokenizer(f.readLine());
int n = Integer.parseInt(x.nextToken());
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if(line == null)
        break;
    else
        line = f.readLine();

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);

    xCoord.add(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
    yCoord.add(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
}
```

Here's the code. Don't know why I'm getting the exception. I have the while loop set to check if line is null.

File:

```
5
0 1
5 4
9 8
0 1
```

Getting the exception at `StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.StringTokenizer.<init>(StringTokenizer.java:199)
at java.util.StringTokenizer.<init>(StringTokenizer.java:236)
at Problems.ProblemOne.main(ProblemOne.java:45)
```

Java Result: 1

Comment: Where do your get your Exception? There is always a line number.

Comment: Check if the file could be opened.

Comment: This would be a good time to read the error message in detail and if that doesn't help use your debugger to step through your code.

Comment: I'm sure if you stepped through this with a debugger, you would find the problem immediately.

Comment: If the file description is correct, it's stating 5 lines, and is then followed by 4 lines of data. If the '5' includes its own line, you need to change your loop test clause to: i < n - 1;

Comment: Please, people, not EVERY question about null pointer exceptions is a duplicate.  This one is different enough, in my opinion, to stand on its own merits.  Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 3):

In your code, you have the statement:

```
if(line == null)
            break;
        else
            line = f.readLine();
```

After that last piece of code, in the 'else' clause, line could equal null as you've just tried to read another line from the file. It would probably be better to have something like:

```
line = f.readLine();
if(line == null) break;
```

Based on the file contents as:

```
4 
0 5 
7 3 
11 -6 
0 2
```

The following example code works without any errors:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class AlanTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        String line = "";
        BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
        StringTokenizer x = new StringTokenizer(f.readLine());
        int n = Integer.parseInt(x.nextToken());
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            line = f.readLine();
            if(line == null) break;

            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
            int xCoord = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            int yCoord = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            System.out.format("%d %d%n", xCoord, yCoord);
        }
    }
}
```

Definitely need to know where you're getting the exception.

Comment: nice catch! And I think you should enclose this in a try-catch block

Comment: Just changed the code. What do you mean by reading another line? The text file is 

4
0 5
7 3
11 -6
0 2

Comment: Every time you call f.readLine(), you're reading the next line from the file. If your file only has one line, you should only ever call  readLine() once.

Comment: Answer edited, added some code that I think more closely matches the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: My file has multiple lines. Sorry for the formatting. 4 is on the first line. 0 and 5 are on the second. Next line is 7 3. Next line is  11 -6. Next line is  0 2.How would I solve my problem with a multiple line file?

Comment: In that case, your original code should work. Which line is the exception happening on?

Comment: @Vonais You should mention the file contents in the question.  The fact that 4 is by itself on the first line is what's causing your error.  But because you've buried it in a comment here, the people who can help you just might not see it.

Comment: @DavidWallace if I'm reading the code correctly, it should actually handle the 4 OK - it's reading a line, parsing out the 4, and then reading 4 lines from the file.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, sorry.  I was looking at your code, @Alan (which would fail) instead of the code in the question.  It doesn't change the fact that Vonais would be well-advised to update the question to show the file contents.

Comment: Yep, would definitely have been useful to see the file contents. I've removed my incorrect example, to save confusion.

Comment: I've added the file. Thanks for the help so far

Comment: Added the exception.

Comment: Did you notice my comment under your question? Your data states 5 lines, and then has 4 lines of data, which will cause this.